# Operations with anonymous functions Matlab

Tags: matlab

One of the things I need to do is calculate this

```
delta_x=@(xn) (f(xn)/df(xn));
```

With this I pretend to evaluate xn, a variable that I previously assigned, in f and df which are anonymous functions and divide its values but in the comand window appears:

```
Error in delta_x=@(xn) (f(xn)/df(xn))
```

I also have writted:

```
delta_x=f/df;
```

where f and df both take as argument xn

But Matlab says:

```
Undefined function 'mdivide' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

I need to take this division, how can i do it?

Comment: Can you show what function handles you are using for `f` and `df`?

Comment: The second line you tried does not seems to make sense. As for the first trial, do f and df return scalar? Are you able to evaluate the ratio with a given xn?

Comment: Please include the full error message in the first case. MATLAB always gives very descriptive error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce same error using the following code but I did not get any error

```
xn = [3 2 3];
%inilize function handler
d1 = @(xn) (fun1(xn)/fun2(xn));
d2 = @(xn) (fun1(xn)./fun2(xn));

%call the function
d1(xn) % = 2.1111
d2(xn) % = 2     3     2

function xout = fun1(x)
xout = x+1;
end

function yout = fun2(y)
yout = y-1;
end
```

Can we know your matlab version?